# Find index of javascript "array of objects" based on object field value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, angularjs

I have a Javascript array of objects and I would like to find index of the array element (object) where particular object's field is matching my search criteria.

That is, array looks like

```
  [{id:1, saved:0, name: "name1"}, {id:26, saved:0, name: "name2"},
    {id:3, saved:0, name: "name3"}, {id:15, saved:0, name: "name4"}]
```

and I would like to locate index of the element where element's id field is equal to, say, 15.
I am using angular and jquery.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'd have to iterate, here's a very simple example

```
var index = null;

for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
    if ( array[i].id == 15 ) {
        index = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

That gets you the index, if you just want to return the object you can do

```
var obj = array.filter(function(obj) {
    return obj.id == 15;
}).shift();
```

Answer (score 6):

With ES6, you could use [`Array#findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

> The **`findIndex()`** method returns the **index** of the first element in the array that satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise `-1` is returned.

```js
var array = [{ id: 1, saved: 0, name: "name1" }, { id: 26, saved: 0, name: "name2" }, { id: 3, saved: 0, name: "name3" }, { id: 15, saved: 0, name: "name4" }],
    index = array.findIndex(({ id }) => id === 15);

console.log(index);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

array.filter is JavaScript's more elegant method for achieving this:

```
var arrr = [{id:1, saved:0, name: "name1"}, {id:26, saved:0, name: "name2"},
{id:3, saved:0, name: "name3"}, {id:15, saved:0, name: "name4"}];

return arrr.filter( function( value ){ return value.id == 15; })[0];
```

Comment: You can get the item this way, but how can I get the index of that item in the array?

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to do this.

You could iterate through the array and do a search.

```
var search = 15;
for(var index=0; index<input.length; index++) {
   if(input[index].id == search) {
       //Do whatever you want to do with this index.
   }
}
```

Or you could create a lookup first

```
var lookup = {};
for(var index=0; index<input.length; index++) {
   var element = input[index];
   lookup[element.id] = element;
   lookup[element.id].index = index;
}
```

Now, in every subsequent look-ups of a search term, you could do the following

```
var search = 15;
if(lookup[search]) {
   var index = lookup[search].index;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.each(json.yourrootjson, function(i, v) {
    if (v.id == "15") {
        alert(v.id);
        alert(v.name);
        alert(v.saved);
        return;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very basic way to do it. Of course, you won't want to use the variables `key` and `match` statically like I did, but I will have to know more about your code to help you with that as well.

```
var array = [{id:1, saved:0, name: "name1"}, {id:26, saved:0, name: "name2"},
             {id:3, saved:0, name: "name3"}, {id:15, saved:0, name: "name4"}]

var key = 'id';
var match = 15;

array.forEach(function(elem, i) {
    if (elem[key] === match) {
        alert(i);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of sources out there but a while loop appears to be the fastest way to iterate an array. Alternatively, Array.map() is in my opinion the cleanest way but actually turns out to be fairly slow.

[Benchmarks](http://jsperf.com/caching-array-length/4)

[Article on loops](https://blogs.oracle.com/greimer/entry/best_way_to_code_a)

```
var array = []; // your array
var len = array.length;

while (len-- ) {
  if ( array[i].id == 15 ) {
    console.log(array[i])
  }
}
```